# how to call the particular constructor of boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost

I have a problem of calling the constructors in boost::variant.
Suppose I have two classes "abc" and "asd" and I have an object declaration something like-

```
class abc
{
   int var;
   float var2;
   public: abc(int a)
           {
             var = a;
            }
   public: abc(inta, float b)
            :var(a), var2(b)
            {}
 };

 class asd
 {
   int var;
   public: asd(int a)
           {
               var = a;
           }
  };

typedef boost::variant<abc,asd> def;
int main()
{
    def my_object;
}
```

my problem is how do I call the constructor of the object my_object?

Comment: You have a typo in `abc`, which means that this is not your real testcase. (Also, your indentation is broken.)

Comment: -1 for not reading the "Basic Usage" page in the Boost Variant documentation.

Comment: I am sorry for the typo.. actually I directly wrote the code in the editor, and my actual program is very big to be pasted here..

Comment: @ankith13: Set your editor to indent with spaces instead of tabs to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

A variant is *not* some multiply-derived custom type, and has its own constructors defined instead. The idiomatic way is to just assign one of the variant types:

```
typedef boost::variant<abc,asd> def;
int main()
{
    def my_object = abc(1);

    my_object = abc(1, .4);
}
```

If you wanted to actually use constructor without without copy-initialization (allthough most compilers will elide the copy) you can write:

```
def my_object(abc(1,.4));
```

Comment: Rather than "without assignment" it should probably be "without copy-initialization", since there's never any assignment :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: yeah that was the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic) (you must have missed it):

> a variant can be constructed directly from any value convertible to
>   one of its bounded types

And:

> Similarly, a variant can be assigned any value convertible to one of
>   its bounded types

So:

```
def my_object = asd(3); // or `def my_object(asd(3));`
my_object = abc(4);
```